# Swig and g++ linking error in Mac 10.6.8

Tags: python, macos, g++, swig

I had some code working under linux and I'm now trying to compile the code under Max 10.6.8. I'm using EPD 32 bit python, g++ version 4.2.1, swig version 2.0.9. Here are the commands I'm using

```
swig -c++ -python pythoncpp.i
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c  pythoncpp_wrap.cxx -I/PATH/Library/EPD/2.7-32/include/python2.7  -I/PATH/local/gsl/include
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c  pythoncpp_wrap.cxx -I/PATH/Library/EPD/2.7-32/include/python2.7  -I/PATH/local/gsl/include
g++  -L/Users/densmore3/local/gsl/lib -lpython -dynamclib pythoncpp.o pythoncpp_wrap.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o _pythoncpp.dylib
```

The first three lines run with error or warnings. But, the linking line  throws the following error

```
Undefined symbols:
 "_PyCapsule_Import", referenced from:
  _SWIG_Python_GetModule in pythoncpp_wrap.o
"_PyCapsule_New", referenced from:
  _SWIG_Python_SetModule in pythoncpp_wrap.o
"_main", referenced from:
  start in crt1.10.6.o
"_PyCapsule_GetPointer", referenced from:
  _SWIG_Python_DestroyModule in pythoncpp_wrap.o  
 ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I fix this error? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my future reference. Using

```
    ld -bundle -flat_namespace -undefined suppress -L/PATH/local/gsl/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o _pythoncpp.so *.o
```

worked to link all the files.